# How to select record with lowest field value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app i fetch some data, it's result could be null, one, or more identical records but with different price value, so i need to iterate in array and select record (array value) with lowest value of price. How can i do this? I ave such code part:

```
@prlist = PriceList.find(:first, :conditions => { :id => @search.map(&:price_list_id)})
```

for example:

```
id name value
1 ololo 15
2 ololo 14
3 ololo 26
```

i need to select 2-d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add order by 'value':

```
@prlist = PriceList.find(:first, :conditions => { :id => @search.map(&:price_list_id)}, :order => 'value')
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that

```
PriceList.where('value = MIN(value)')
```

should work for you (at least for MySQL, Postgres and SQLite3 ).

If you only need the minimum value (not the entire row):

```
PriceList.minimum('value')
```

Comment: `PriceList.where('value = MIN(value)')` won't work with PostgreSQL, you can't use an aggregate in a WHERE clause.

Comment: `PriceList.minimum('value')`: nice, short and clean :)